Make Posrgres Docker Container accessible with SSH only
AFAIK the denying the access from the internet to the Docker container with database (Postgres in my case) is the basic security measure. But how to do it? My current docker-compose.yaml is:
version: "3.5"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Production-Database
    ports: [ "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}" ]

    environment:

      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/data/example.jp

volumes:
  DatabaseData: {}


You don't show what's in [ "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}" ], but
I would assume it translates to something like '5432:5432', which is equivalent to this in short format:
ports:
  - 0.0.0.0:5432:5432/tcp

Meaning by default you publish the port to the outside world to see (0.0.0.0). Change this to:
ports:
  - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432

and the port is only bound to localhost, and no-one outside of it can no longer access it.
